# How to install VLC player in asp.net if user has not install it

Tags: c#

Ok, I can explain it clearly,the user need to play a video file but they had no player for example a VLc Player i need to notify him there is no required player and then i ask him to install the player and install is it possible

Comment: Or you can use any of the standard ways to display video in a web page, eg use Flash or the <video> tag. Just look at YouTube

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET is a server technology, and it is not possible via ASP.NET to install an app on the user's machine.

But via JavaScript it is more likely, and it seems some made a JS script: http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/VLC/